# Find all primes $p$ for which $x^2+2x+4\equiv 0 \pmod p$ is solvable. Am I correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Getting ready for an exam, I would like to focus on the correctness of my solution, final results and assumptions, and would appreciate any comment regarding it or even additional solutions\corrections.

**Attempt**: $x^2+2x+4=(x+1)^2+3\equiv0 \pmod p \iff (x+1)^2\equiv -3 \pmod p \iff ({-3\over p})\equiv 1 ({-1\over p})({3\over p})\equiv 1 \pmod p\iff (-1)^{p-1\over 2}({p\over 3})^2({3\over p})\equiv ((-1)^{p-1\over 2})^2({p\over 3})\equiv p \pmod 3$

For $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ the equation aforementioned is solvable, whereas for $p\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ it isn't. (For $p=3$ it is, anyway.)

Now that seems dubiously easy for a full question in an exam, which is why I could really use any observation, making sure I have not overlooked something significant.

Comment: A typo. Got me a little confused. That happens to me with common patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primes $2$ and $3$ are special, but easy to deal with. The rest is a Legendre symbol calculation.

First deal with primes $p$ of the form $4k+1$. Then $(-1/p)=1$, so we want $(3/p)=1$, or by Reciprocity $(p/3)=1$. That happens if $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, so we want $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$,  $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, that is, $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$.

Next we deal with $p\gt 3$ of the form $4k+3$. Then $(-1/p)=-1$ and by Reciprocity $(3/p)=-(p/3)$. Now I am sure you can finish.  There will be simplification.

**Remark:** Your approach was correct. However, I am a little nervous about that kind of calculation. It is usually safer to separate out things on the basis of congruence class modulo $4$.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. I will try to solve it that way. Does it mean my solution is not much admissible?

Comment: You are very much correct.